# How to correctly assign function pointers to elements of typedef struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, maple

Here I provide the concrete example nevertheless. I have a typedef (from a header file `maplec.h` defining OpenMaple).

```
typedef struct {
void (M_DECL *textCallBack) ( void *data, int tag, char *output );
void (M_DECL *errorCallBack) ( void *data, M_INT offset, char *msg );

...

} MCallBackVectorDesc, *MCallBackVector;
```

In my code I want to assign the callback functions to use. In the examples from the manual (http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=4383&view=html) this is done with

```
MCallBackVectorDesc cb = {  textCallBack, 
                               0,   /* errorCallBack not used */ 
...                           
};
```

However I want to keep a reference to this variable `cb` in a structure which I defined as

```
struct open_maple {
MCallBackVectorDesc *call_back_vector;

};
```

Then I initialize with

```
open_maple->call_back_vector = (MCallBackVectorDesc *)malloc((size_t)sizeof(MCallBackVectorDesc));

(open_maple->call_back_vector)->textCallBack = &textCallBack;
(open_maple->call_back_vector)->errorCallBack = 0;
```

This code does not produce any compiler warnings nor Segfaults, but I do not seem to receive any calls of textCallBack either, while the online example version would work. I tried other definitions and assignments, but always got warnings or Segfaults.

It boils down to the question: How do I correctly assign the pointers to the callback functions collected in the typedef struct if I do not want to assign them at initialization (in the declaration of the variable cb)?

**Edit 1**

It has been suggested below that the error occurs because I am referencing the `textCallBack` function as `&textCallBack` function which generates a pointer from a pointer. However the example works neither with nor without the `&`. Note also that the following code works:

```
 /* some standard libraries */
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

    void function(void){
      printf("IAMHERE\n");
    };

    int main()
    {

      void (*myfunction)(void) = &function;

      myfunction();

      return 0;
    }
```

I am using `gcc -o test test.c` to compile it.

**Edit 2**

Some more investigations showed that the problem is supposedly related to my use of OpenMaple.

Comment: `open_maple` is a structure, you directly use as variable? no compiler warning / error? and when you initialize `open_maple`, it looks like you declare it as pointer to `struct open_maple`, do you allocate memory for it?

Comment: @Do you try this `(open_maple->call_back_vector)->textCallBack = textCallBack;`?

Comment: @yongzhy I declare and allocate `open_maple` with `struct open_maple *open_maple = (struct open_maple *)malloc((size_t)sizeof(struct open_maple));`

Comment: @BlackMamba Yes, I tried this. Please see the edit above.

Comment: Something I don't know how to read in the code is the `MCallBackVectorDesc, *MCallBackVector;` at the end of the `typedef`. Does this define two types? I tried to work with `MCallBackVector`, but I could not so I tried using `MCallBackVectorDesc`.

Comment: Yes, that's defining `MCallBackVectorDesc` as a name for the struct type and `MCallBackVector` as a name for pointers to the type. Without the `typedef` keyword, it would define the former as a variable holding an instance of the struct and the latter as a variable holding a pointer to instances of the struct.

Comment: We're really not going to be able to give you a complete answer for this until we know what the M_DECL structure looks like, and how your local variable `textCallBack` was defined. Without that information, we're guessing.

Answer (score -1):

textCallBack is defined as a pointer to function.

You're taking the address of it -- pointer to pointer to function.

Is that really what you intend to store into your structure?

Comment: Please see the edit I made to the question. Note that I tried without the ampersand too.

Comment: For functions, the address of a function is a pointer to the function., it's not a pointer to pointer. `&function == function`. Even dereferencing a function just evaluates to a function pointer. `*function == function`

Comment: That's a special case for function names, related to a change made in the ANSI C timeframe. (Before that, you did need to use `&function` to get a pointer to the function, but it was decided that this was a mistake in the design of K&R C and the special-case was added to make it work "the way it should have" while not breaking old programs.) So the "edit 1" example is misleading; if `textCallBack` is declared as a pointer to function, & on it really will yield pointer to pointer to function.